# ASP.NET EnableViewStateMac cross-site scripting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We did an external security audit about one of our applications, which resultet in the following warning:

> *Description*: Microsoft ASP.NET EnableViewStateMac cross-site scripting
>
> *Concern*: This application is prone to this vulnerability because of a failure to properly sanitize user-supplied input, allowing an
> attacker to conduct cross-site scripting attacks.

I found [a bit of information](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/09/09/farewell-enableviewstatemac/) about that issue. Mainly saying: Do **never** set this to false.

I checked our code and there is no `EnableViewStateMac` - Setting anywhere in our soulution, so AFAIK this should mean we have the default setting of true which is good.

Are there any other possibilities that this can appear? Any other setting that includes the EnableViewStateMac?

We use the .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: have you check it on the individual aspx pages? Whether I remember correctly, it is a page tag property

Comment: I did a fulltext-search on "EnableViewStateMac" on the Solution. In addition we do not really have ASPX-Pages but only HTML (via MVC)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add if EnableViewStateMac is missing on individual page level

```
<%@ Page EnableViewStateMac="true" %>
```

and

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="true" />
```

Comment: AFAIK this should be the default setting?